# What do precision and scale mean in the Time datatype in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

When creating a `TIME` datatype, SQL Server seems to default to `time(7)`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb677243.aspx) states that the precision and scales can range from (8, 0) to (16, 7).

Now, hours (00-23), minutes (00-59) and seconds (00-59) can have at most two digits each, so their precision can't be more than 6 all combined. If we add milliseconds (000-999) to the equation, then precision can go up to 9. There is no decimal point, so scale should always be zero.

Then what do values like (8, 0) or (16, 7) mean for precision (unless precision counts the colon separaters between hours, minutes and seconds) and scale? Shouldn't the precision be just 9 (or 12 if we count the colons) and scale always zero? How to pick the precision of time datatype from the available (0-7) values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `time` (and `datetime2`), the precision is inferred by the scale. You as user can only chose the scale (which is the number of second fraction digits), the precision is then given. This controls the fraction part of seconds only, e.g. `(0)` is full seconds only, `(3)` gives you millisecond resolution, `(7)` 100ns resolution.

The precision is the (inferred) number of characters at a given scale, including colons and decimal separator for seconds. Therefore, with `(0)`, this results in a string representation such as `hh:mm:ss` (8 characters), while `(3)` results in `hh:mm:ss.fff` (12 characters) and `(7)` is `hh:mm:ss.fffffff` (16 characters). This corresponds to the numbers given in the table of the MSDN page you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
DECLARE @timeval AS TIME(7) = '12:34:56.1234567';

SELECT  @timeval Value16_7Precision,
        LEFT(CAST(@timeval AS NVARCHAR(20)), 16) First16 ,
        LEFT(CAST(@timeval AS NVARCHAR(20)), 9) First9 ,
        RIGHT(CAST(@timeval AS NVARCHAR(20)), 7) Last7;
```

To get this:

```
Value16_7Precision  First16             First9      Last7
12:34:56.1234567    12:34:56.1234567    12:34:56.   1234567
```

For `TIME(0) = (8,0)`, only the first 8 characters are considered: `12:34:56`